# C#: Cover Images are not viewed in ePub document

Tags: c#, html, image, epub

I am creating an application to generate books as ePub. I am allowing the user to upload front and back cover. It is placed in the same folder of the HTML documents.
I am using ePubSharp library file to convert to eBook. But the Cover Pages are not displayed in the ePub document. I need the user to define the front cover and back cover of the document. I don't know what is the issue. Can anyone have any solution?

Comment: Rename your epub to .zip, open it, and see where the images are, and what paths the html actually point at.

Comment: Images are not present in any folder

Comment: then I assume you forgot to actually put in any commands to tell ePubSharp to insert them in the epub file. Just embedding them in the documents probably isn't enough.

Comment: I have specified the complete folder path which in turn contains the html files in sub folder and images in the root folder.

Comment: Then perhaps ePubSharp doesn't work like you think it works. Look deeper into it. Read the user manuals, google for usage examples specific to including images. As it is, [you have not even shown what you did](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so people here can do nothing to help you.